# Sum in a df using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My sales table:
[Sales Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCCPc.png)

I need to sum the daily sales for every hour for each warehouse based on the below info [Groupby Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hrcg.png).

Issue is that the Groupby is not fixed. The Stores will change for a warehouse and so this has to be dynamic. I am trying to create a dictionary for the Warehouse and the respective stores and then link it to the dataframe where the Sum operation will be carried out.

End output needed is Datewise - Hourwise Total Sales data for each warehouse.

In future when i need to modify the stores for a warehouse all I need to do is update the dictionary and automatically the Sum is carried out in the df.

I am unable to map the dictionary to the df.

Comment: Can you describe more info about what do you want? SQL Script? C#?Python?R? And please copy paste your table and expected result in text based.

Comment: Hi Siahaan. I am unable to attach the Excel tables. Can I email them to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your dictionary as you wish and then use `DataFrame.from_dict()` function of Pandas to make a dataframe from it.
Next, you can perform `groupby` along with any calculations.

The full script would look like this:

```
data = {"Warehouse_id": [732, 732, 733, 733, 734, 734, 735, 735,
                           736, 736, 737], 
           "date": ["1/09/2023", "1/09/2023", "1/09/2023", "1/09/2023",
                   "1/09/2023", "2/09/2023", "2/09/2023", "2/09/2023", 
                   "2/09/2023", "3/09/2023", "3/09/2023"],
          "Collection_hour": [9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 9],
           "Store_1": [35, 10, 15, 11,22, 53, 124, 236, 378, 334, 208],
           "Store_2": [20, 10, 14, 10, 32, 79, 162, 340, 445, 418, 326]
          }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

grouped_by_sum = df.groupby(by=["Warehouse_id", "date", "Collection_hour"]).sum()
```

The outcome of grouped_by_sum will be this: [image: grouped_by_sum outcome]